# WordPress is Inserting images into Post as HTTP and not HTTPS

Tags: images, ssl, https

I've logged into my site in HTTPS and I'm editing on a specific post. I've dragged an image to the edit window and am now inserting an image.

The thing is WordPress is inserting the image as HTTP instead of HTTPS. It shows the URL as HTTP clearly and uneditable.

[image]

1. Is there a way to change this value to HTTPS? I'm guessing no.
2. Is there a way to tell WordPress to enter the relative URL instead of absolute URL? I'm guessing no too.

With SSL Certificates now free to any website I think this issue may come up more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Change the site URL to be HTTPS based instead of HTTP. In other words go fully HTTPS on your site. If you need mixed content solution for serving your HTML both as HTTP and HTTPS you will need some dynamic detection and manipulation of URLs in the contents or serve as protocol neutral url.
2. very bad idea. The best you can get is protocol neutral Urls.

You can try something like

```
add_filter('the_content','wpse_211864',1000,1);

// remove 'http:' part from any mention of the site url
function wpse_211864($content) {
    return str_replace(siteurl(),str_replace('http:','',siteurl()),$content);
}
```

Comment: I do not see a site URL setting anywhere. I forgot to mention I'm using wpmu. Fwiw i checked both the network and individual site settings and did not see any place to change the site URL.

Comment: yes, there is no such setting in wpmu. You can overide the defaults by usng the constants as explained here - https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Comment: Why is using relative URLs a bad idea? If the site is on HTTP then the base URL will be HTTP:// my site. If the site is on HTTPS the base URL would be HTTPS. This would make the images show up without regard to the protocol.

Comment: OK. I'll update it in the wp config file. Thanks. I would add that override suggestion to part of of your answer.

Comment: relative UTRs are bad because same image might be included in two different posts and the URL of a post might change which will complicate your life if you will need to update your content every ime you do so.

Comment: @MarkKaplun I suspect the OP was referring to protocol-relative URLs, which you referred to as protocol-neutral. It's weird to me that WP doesn't use them as standard.

Comment: @BennettMcElwee, maybe, that is the problem of using "relative" without specifying relative to what ;) part of why I used the word "neutral" here I guess. Anyway, someone on the internet clamed it is anti-pattern and core developers read him and believed him, so don't expect it to happen any time soon.

Comment: Yeah. I don't understand why this issue is not a lot bigger -- it will affect everyone who moves their site from http to https!