# WP media attachment location vs permalink

Tags: attachments, media-library, https

Yesterday I moved my sites from http://www.example.com to  (secure site and removed the www).  Now when I look at an attachment page I see the File URL as the old http://www ... but the page permalink at https://.

I have even deleted the original photos and re-uploaded new ones, thinking that might solve it, but it does not.  The domain is properly set (https://) in Wordpress Settings/General.  The site works fine ... and the switch to https went much more smoothly than I had anticipated ... except for this issue.

Has anyone encountered similar?  Or know what/where I need to change something?

Thank you for any info/advice.

Comment: How have you done the change? Have you followed the [instructions for changing the URL of a WordPress site](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Changing_Your_Domain_Name_and_URLs)?

Answer (score 0):

I think a possible solution could be following codesnippet from [Mark Kaplun](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/211867/15605).

To solve issues with this you could remove the `http` part and Wordpress will/should use `https` instead.

Because the rest of your website is working correctly I assume that further settings are correct and will do their job as wished.

```
add_filter('the_content','wpse_217012',1000,1);
// remove 'http:' part from any mention of the site url
function wpse_217012($content) {
    return str_replace(siteurl(),str_replace('http:','',siteurl()),$content);
}
```

Please add the snippet to `functions.php` (*make a copy first*) or to a `plugin`.

> **Note:** Of course is this a solution to achieve a positive result and actually
>   not pointing on the cause of your problem as it.
>   I personally would not use a `redirect` done by code in `.htaccess` because, as mentioned by yourself already, the rest is working.
>   Maybe there is a `plugin` or own code somewhere in `functions.php` which is causing the problem? Please take also a look at these possibilities.

*If I am totally wrong, please let me know and I will remove the answer to prevent other users here on wpse will use the (incorrect)code for an equal problem.*